# Rails 2.3.2 and SHOW TABLES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have annoying problem with SHOW TABLES in my Rails 2.3.2 APP - it is slowing my APP very deep. The question is, how to get rid of SHOW TABLES usage and where it is used in Rails framework? From APP logs I can see that it is being used all the time.

Thank you!

config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SHOW TABLES" is ORM-dependent SQL query, it fires with every action to provide classes reload in development mode. How much time does the query take?

Comment: Same problem for production. Query is about 12.5 ms and more. And it is shooting out sometimes 4-5 times per action.

Comment: it's shooting per each table. what's your config/environments/production.rb code?

Comment: can you check what's the environment on your production server, what's one used to serve the application? Is this file empty **./log/production.log**?

Comment: Do you have **./tmp/always_restart.txt**? If so, delete it

Comment: Producion.log is not empty and I don't have always_restart.txt file in tmp/ directory.

Comment: grep ./log/production.log "SELECT"

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar problem in Rails 3.0 and was able to fix it using the [gist](https://gist.github.com/2134218) pointed to from [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5459). Looks like it's fixed in Rails 3.2.

I added ar_patch.rb to config/initializers with this code:

```
unless Rails.env.development?
  require "active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter"

  module ActiveRecord
    module ConnectionAdapters
      class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractAdapter
        extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable
        memoize :tables, :pk_and_sequence_for, :columns
      end
    end
  end
end
```